# How can I build a simple network to tests DASH adaptive bitrate streaming technique in the omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, mpeg-dash, inet

I would like to create simple network including one server and few clients downloading video chunks using DASH technique in `omnet++`. Connections between clients and server is not a problem for me but I do not know how can I implement DASH technique algorithm between clients and server. Is in `omnet++` and `inet framework` any good practice to accomplish this goal?